# Confusion about Sodium Nitroprusside

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, oxidation-state

In Sodium Nitroprusside and related compounds (eg. brown ring complex) why is the oxidation state of NO +1 and not zero? It seems pretty unusual without any explanation.

Could anyone please explain this, and maybe provide a satisfactory theoretical explanation for the exhibition of 'unusual oxidation state'?

Comment: I have checked these. There is no proper theoretical explanation, though.

Comment: I'd like to know when NO exists in 0 and when it exists +1, with some sort of theoretical explanation.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Did you delete those links? Even vaguely related stuff should stay linked. Also why you didn't CV duplicate?

Comment: Those links do not answer my confusion. Some say that Fe is in +3 and NO is in -1, while some say that both are in +1 oxidation state. Which one is right?

Comment: @user28968 read the answers in by F'x and DavePhD, they agree that Fe is 3+ and NO is -1, point to literature that supports this, and that both being +1 was a misconception.